# Выполнение алгоритма при каждом нажатии

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, клавиатура

Мне нужно, чтобы всегда при нажатии кнопки выполнялся один и тот же код (я засунула это в функцию).
При моём скрипте функция выполняется только один раз.

`newButton.onclick = gp();`

Как сделать вроде "Выполнять всегда при нажатии на кнопку"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно присваивать ссылку на функцию (или выражение с функцией), а не результат вызова функции: в вашем коде функция выполняется один раз и возвращаемое ею значение присваивается `onclick`. Попробуйте так:

```
newButton.onclick = gp;
```

Подробнее: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick